# Why JDBC treats port zero as same as empty (default) port?

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

On the system I'm developing I have to connect with several databases on different hosts and ports the problem is:
I'm trying to reach jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb with a JDBC connection and everything is fine, but I can also pass jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:0/testdb and the connection still works.

Reading JDBC docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

I found "host:port is the host name and port number of the computer hosting your database. If not specified, the default values of host and port are 127.0.0.1 and 3306, respectively."

But the port was specified as ZERO.
Should I ignore ZERO as a port?

Comment: You should avoid 0-1024 ports, consider them as not available...

Comment: Is 3306 the default for mariadb? The driver may know that and treat port 0 as being undefined and thus to use the default.

Comment: Up to the driver implementation. Are you using MariaDB only?

Comment: I'm also using Oracle and Postgresql databases

Comment: Yes @JosephLarson the default is 3306 on mariadb server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 0 is a reserved port and is not available for general use. (ref: [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), via [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180492)). Apparently the MariaDB JDBC driver recognizes that and simply uses the default port value (3306) if port 0 is specified.